# Change Magento2 attribute code Programmatically

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, code

In Magento 2, there is a `product attribute code` with `space`.(I know, Magento will not allow to create `product_attribute_code` with space or with Capital letters).

Now, I need to change/update that `product_attribute_code` (code alone) to without space.

How to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Magento does not allow to change the attribute code once it is created. You need to remove this attribute from attribute set and create the new attribute with same name without space and proceed.

I will not recommend to do this but if you really wants to change the attribute code you can change it from database. The attribute code value saved to eav_attribute table you can search for your attribute and change the code. (This is not recommended).

Comment: Yes, I changed already. But I need it via code

Comment: @Saravanan DS Can you please explain what exactly you wants to do? From code?

Comment: As I mentioned, I need to change/update that product_attribute_code (code alone) to without space.

Comment: How did you create the product attribute code with space? because Magento does not allow to create such.

Comment: try it. If you creating through code means, it doesnot show any errors. It will be created. YOu will get error only manual creation.